# apache,php,mysql compatible to care2x

Tags: php, mysql, apache

My boss want me to install a version of CARE2X web app on a server.
I downloaded the latest version from
 http://sourceforge.net/projects/care2002/files/CARE2X/Care2x-HIS-2.6.27.zip/download
  unzipped it and installed on my_domain which can be accessed through my_domain/care2x/
Now it produces some error on some pages, while reading manuals and documentations about care2x, i found out that care2x system requirements(apache,php,mysql versions) does not meet
the requirements installed on the server(latest versions).

Can someone help me?

Update: it sometimes produces error and sometimes not. Previously i installed the same version on another_domain/care2x and saved a screen shot of the error.
[image]

Further more is it possible to upgrade the care2x or edit the code so that it becomes compatible to new versions of its system requirements or is there any other work-around?

Comment: Cant see any errors on the site, but that software looks ancient - the system requirements page lists apache 1.x and **windows 98** If you edit your question with actual details of the errors you are getting, maybe you can get some help

Answer (score 1):

This project has not been updated (with anything meaningful) [since 2011](https://sourceforge.net/p/care2002/code/ci/ed1c57234fda124e37d2cf03869af6dea034b884/log/?path=). You should forget about it.

You may be able to suppress the issued warnings by configuring the php setting `display_errors` to `off`, but this does not solve any errors and probably even hides more severe errors.

There have been significant changes in the programming with PHP since then. [This script](https://sourceforge.net/p/care2002/code/ci/master/tree/index.php) uses obsolete `session_register` calls, is build on `register_globals` functionality, uses old superglobals (`global $REMOTE_ADDR;`), uses [smarty in version 2](https://sourceforge.net/p/care2002/code/ci/master/tree/classes/smarty/) while [version 3](http://www.smarty.net/) is the current stable one, … and it's just the start page I've taken a look at now!

This is definitely nothing one should consider to install now as a "new" solution.

Best case: It does not work. Worst case: You are installing a huge security hole on your server.